# Async method reading mysql table produce list with duplicated elements

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core-webapi, mysql-connector

Async method returns list with duplicated elements. It is async method which is using mysql connector to connect with database. Then it execute query (SELECT *) and by using MySqlDataReader - I save and add to list rows until last ReadAsync() call.

Asynchronous programming is still black magic for me - I would appreciate any feedback or indicating unlogical code lines with explanation.

This method will be used in my web api controller and method purpose is to return all entries from 'Posts' table. Code is working fine when I 'reset' temp object each loop by using
`temp = new Post();` but I assume it is unacceptable ? **What if my database would have not 15 but 15000 entries?**

`

```
public async Task<List<Post>> GetPostsAsync()
        {
            List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
            Post temp = new Post();

            try
            {
                await _context.conn.OpenAsync();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("USE idunnodb; SELECT * FROM Posts;", _context.conn);

                await using MySqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                while(await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    temp.PostID = (int)reader[0];
                    temp.UserID = (int)reader[1];
                    temp.PostDate = reader[2].ToString();
                    temp.PostTitle = reader[3].ToString();
                    temp.PostDescription = reader[4].ToString();
                    temp.ImagePath = reader[5].ToString();

                    posts.Add(temp);

                }

                await _context.conn.CloseAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<Post>().ToList();
            }

            return posts;
        }
```

`

Comment: What does `duplicated elements` mean? Do you mean that except for the index ID, the other columns of the retrieved data are the same? There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. Or actually you want an explanation document about [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Hi, it means that every element in my 'posts' list is exactly the same, all fields of Post are the same and they equal to data of last row in mySql 'Posts' table. I debugged code line by line and first iteration is correct - it is adding object with data from first row. Second iteration added second object to list with data of second row but also changed first object in list so now posts[0] and posts[1] are identical..

Comment: Have you tried putting `Post temp = new Post();` in the `reader.ReadAsync()` loop?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that it works when I create new Post object every time but can I do it in different way? I just don't understand why it isn't working without it and I am worried it would be very memory - expensive if there would be like 100 or 1000 times more rows in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can only read data by looping through `MySqlDataReader`, according to your code logic, you need to read each piece of data, and then add them to the List one by one for output.

Your code is behaving this way because `temp` has been declared & instantiated outside of your `reader.ReadAsync()` statement, you are updating the same object reference each time around the loop which is why you are seeing repeating objects in your list.

So you need to instantiate in `reader.ReadAsync()` loop:

```
while(await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    Post temp = new Post();
    ...
}
```